# Xcode-style font picker

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fonts, appkit

I'd like to add a font picker in my app. Xcode's Interface Builder has a great implementation which is used in Xcode's own preferences' window too.

It's the one with a little 'T' button (seemingly) inside the font name text field itself.

Is this a standard cocoa implementation?

Comment: I am currently investigating NSFontPanel .. I needed an answer myself, but oh well..

Comment: I want to use this control as well. Did you ever come up with a comparable solution?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to roll your own. See [Subclassing NSControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/Tasks/SubclassingNSControl.html). You'll subclass NSTextField and NSTextFieldCell. Read the entire guide, actually. Once you've got a good understanding, then you can override the drawing/geometry routines to return a rect whose width is slightly smaller (small enough to leave room for the font "button"). Then draw your font button. You'll respond to its mouse events on the font button the same as you would for any NSView.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard control for the preview text box with the button, but there is the standard NSFontPanel class that you can use to let users select the font once the 'T' button has been clicked.

Best idea is probably to override NSTextFieldCell. I've been able to get the desired appearance by overriding -drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:, and passing a slightly less wide frame when calling through to super, then drawing the button myself. You'd also have to implement the mouse tracking of the button yourself, but you could probably just create your own NSButtonCell instance and call through to it for a few methods with the sub-rect for the button.

For convenience, you may also want to create a NSTextField subclass that uses this cell instead of a straight NSTextFieldCell, but if you're loading stuff from a XIB, you can just change the class of the cell in the XIB and leave it in a regular text field view.